# Kaltura Upload Video - Error 413

Tags: android, inputstream, http-error, kaltura

I am using the Kaltura client library for Android to upload a video.

It successfully creates the entry on the server, but when it gets to the point of actually uploading the video file, it fails with Error 413 - Request Entity Too Large.

```
KalturaMediaEntry mediaEntry = new KalturaMediaEntry();
mediaEntry.name = title;
mediaEntry.mediaType = KalturaMediaType.VIDEO;

mediaEntry = kalturaClient.getMediaService().add(mediaEntry);

KalturaUploadToken token = new KalturaUploadToken();
token = kalturaClient.getUploadTokenService().add(token);

ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
InputStream inStream = resolver.openInputStream(selectedVideoUri);

Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedVideoUri, null, null, null, null);
int sizeIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE);
cursor.moveToFirst();
long size = cursor.getLong(sizeIndex);
cursor.close();


// this fails
kalturaClient.getUploadTokenService().upload(token.id, inStream, title, size);
```

I've tried using an extremely short video (2 seconds) and even that failed. Not sure where to look from here.

Comment: What is the size of the file that you try to upload?

Comment: @Cr6 any resolution on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the request has some incorrect parameters.

These are the parameters it's looking for:

- uploadTokenId (string)
- outFile
- resume (boolean)
- finalChunk (boolean)
- resumeAt (number)

[Source](https://developer.kaltura.com/api-docs/service/uploadToken/action/upload)

If the file is too large you may have to chunk it and upload the chunks. Kaltura has [documentation and an example](https://developer.kaltura.com/api-docs/Ingest_and_Upload_Media/create-new-kaltura-entry-and-upload-video-file-using-kaltura-api.html) in their developer resources.

[image: Sreenshot of Request Parameters]

Answer (score 0):

chunk upload using Kaltura kaltura-typescript-client

Kaltura apis support the chunk upload out of the box, for that we should not pass any parameters.

```
const uploadAction: KalturaUploadRequest<KalturaUploadToken> = new UploadTokenUploadAction({
    uploadTokenId: token,
    fileData: file,
});
```